# Custom metadata in Firestore Audit Logs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to add some custom metadata to Read/Write requests in Firestore and be able to see it later in Logs Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Firestore doesn't support that at all.  You can only read and write the contents of documents with the provided APIs. There is no custom metadata other than what you choose to put in the document.